# How to combine two select fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to combine the values of two select fields in a form into a single variable before submitting the form.

Here is  the just of my code:

In new.html.erb (for RoR):

```
<%= form_for :character, url: characters_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <p>
     <%= f.label :alignment %><br>
     <%= f.select :alignment_lr, options_for_select([" ","Chaotic","Neutral","Lawful"], disabled: " ", selected: " ") %>
     <%= f.select :alignment_ud, options_for_select([" ","Good","Neutral","Evil"], disabled: " ", selected: " ") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This generates the following html:

```
<p>
  <label for="character_alignment">Alignment</label><br>
  <select id="character_alignment_lr" name="character[alignment_lr]">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=" "> </option>
    <option value="Chaotic">Chaotic</option>
    <option value="Neutral">Neutral</option>
    <option value="Lawful">Lawful</option></select>
  <select id="character_alignment_ud" name="character[alignment_ud]">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=" "> </option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Neutral">Neutral</option>
    <option value="Evil">Evil</option></select>
</p>
```

How can I combine the values selected for `:alignment_lr` and `:alignment_ud` to equal something like `alignment.value = alignment_lr.value + ' ' + alignment_ud.value`?

I am open to using javascript or jquery in order to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not necessary to use scripting at all. You appear to have no real interest in keeping the components of your alignment variable as separate fields in your model, so the short answer is: don't do it.

You can use virtual attributes to record a value in your form and then apply logic in your model to create the actual value that gets saved to the database via ActiveRecord. Virtual attributes allows your form to have fields that do not directly correspond to fields in your model.

1. Create a migration that drops your "`alignment_lr`" and "`alignment_ud`" columns and replaces them with a single column "alignment." Ideally, you would have your database normalized in such a way that every alignment combination is saved to an alignments table, and you'd be saving a key, rather than a dynamically generated string, but this is a different issue;
2. In your `Character.rb` model, add an `attr_accessor` line:

   ```
   class Character < ActiveRecord::Base

       attr_accessor: :alignment_lr, :alignment_ud
   ```
3. In your `characters_controller.rb` file, add `:alignment_lr` and `:alignment_ud` to your strong params (`character_params` method)
4. You can still write your `f.select` statements exactly as you already have them.
5. In your `characters_controller.rb` `create` method:

   ```
   @character.combine_alignment(@character.alignment_lr, @character.alignment_ud)
   ```
6. In your Character.rb, add the `combine_alignment` method:

   ```
   def combine_alignment(left_right, up_down)
      return "#{left_right} #{up_down}"
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @MarsAtomic. I'm now getting the following error: 
`NoMethodError in CharactersController#create 


undefined method `left_right' for #<Character:0x5d1cad0>`. The line in the extracted source says it's from the `return "#{left_right up_down}"` line in step 6. Any ideas how to stop this? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. First I changed `return "#{left_right up_down}` to `return "#{left_right} #{up_down}"`. Which then returned an error that alignment was blank. So I added `@character.alignment =` to `@character.combine_alignment(@character.alignment_lr, @character.alignment_ud)` and it worked flawlessly! Thanks a lot for the solution. It integrates perfectly with the existing form that I have.

Comment: My apologies. Here I was, thinking I was crafting a thorough and careful guide, and I managed to throw in an interpolation error. Fixed now, and I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to add a hidden input to store both values;

```
<input id="character_alignment" type="hidden" name="character[alignment]" value=""/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// for the first select
$("#character_alignment_lr").change(function(){
    setCharacterAlignment();
});


// for the second select
$("#character_alignment_lr").change(function(){
    setCharacterAlignment();    
});

});

function setCharacterAlignment()
{
    // get dropdown selected option
    var val1 = $('#character_alignment_lr option:selected').val();
    var val2 = $('#character_alignment_ud option:selected').val();

    // set hidden input value
    $("#character_alignment").val(val1 + " " + val2);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You could also just update the hidden field when the form is submitted, using `.submit()`. Unless the value is used somewhere else as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways:

In the controller inside the create method you can put:

```
alignment.value = params[:character][:alignment_lr] + ' ' + params[:character][:alignment_ud]
```

or

```
@character = Character.new(character_params)
@character.alignment = @character.alignment_lr + " " + @character.alignment_ud
```

If you want to use javascript you could do it with a hidden field that concatenates both fields as shown by @Ceparu Stefan